# How do dragons cross the sea?

Tags: game-of-thrones, dragons

In season 6 finale, Queen Daenerys Targaryen brought her entire fleet to Westeros.

We saw the dragons flapping around the ships. They must be a few tons in weight by then and none of the ships was big enough for them to land on. The biggest was carrying the Queen, and it was just an average size ship.

So how do Dragons cross the sea? Can they maintain a several weeks flight without rest?

Comment: Related M&TV Question: [Did the dragons fly along with Daenerys' fleet?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/56197/11244)

Comment: If some large birds like [the albatross can fly thousands of miles without ever touching land](http://www.independent.co.uk/environment/nature/how-the-unflappable-albatross-can-travel-10000-miles-in-a-single-journey-8945618.html), why is it *so* outlandish that dragons can do similar? (Yes, yes, biology and physics don't scale so well from smaller to larger animals, but then again... dragons don't exist and are magical in nature).

Comment: There is no indication that It was Westeros where Dany's fleet was shown. For all we know it could have been Slaver's bay. Dragons can travel at far greater speed than other modes of transport. E.g. Princess Rhaenyra and her uncle Prince Daemon used to race each other's dragons from KL to Dragonstone and back, all in one day. So what might take weeks or months for ships, would take only hours or days for dragons

Comment: Also, [See Bar-tailed godwit's flying record of flying from Alaska to Newzealand in a non-stop flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar-tailed_godwit#Migrations). That's 11,680 KMs.

Comment: The ships will also periodically need to stop on dry land to take on fresh water and fresh food (they'll have dry food, but they'll want to vary their diet if they don't want [scurvy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scurvy#Early_modern_era)). They'll probably also need to exercise the horses if they want them to not be lame when they arrive (and they'll likely also want to give the sea-phobic dothraki periodic breaks from throwing up over the side of the boat so they don't mutiny!). I really don't understand why people think the dragons getting a rest is the difficult part in this operation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<nerd rant>`

The answer to this question is basically four parts: *(1)* size of the straight in question, *(2)* the starting point of the voyage and *(3)* route taken, and *(4)* the speed of the ships. Let's look at all of these. [Please reference this map for details](http://viewers-guide.hbo.com/game-of-thrones/season-6/episode-10/map/location/77/bay-of-dragons) on the answers given.

1. There is not any proper distance given (that I know of) so we can assume a long or short distance at will. I personally don't like this one either, but it stands.
2. On the provided map you will see that on the starting point *Bay of Dragons* (formerly *Slavers' Bay*) is on the south side of the continent so there will be some time of sailing near the mainland, giving the dragons opportunity to rest as needed.
3. If you notice on the map above, there is a chain of small islands between the closest points (Sunspear and Lys) to the south. So the dragons would not even need to fly the whole trip at once.
4. Ships of this type would be extremely slow compared to the quick flight of a dragon. If we want to be overly generous about the ships used and say that they could move at the speed of a Caravel, that is still only an [average of 4 knots](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vaucher/History/Ships_Discovery/), so a several weeks - months trip via ship would be much shorter; days or less. If we assume a meager 45 MPH (72.4 km/h) for the dragons it would take a ship 10 hours to travel what a dragon would in 1. So even if we put a distance between the two continents at 350 miles (563 km) a dragon would make the trip in 8 hours and still have time to stop for coffee on the way, the fleet would on the other hand needs 76 hours, and that's with favorable weather.

`</nerd rant>`

Comment: Dragonfire-roasted coffee is the best coffee, I hear.